# Obtaining number of rows Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Just a quick question..

Following opening a text file in a separate definition (no classes used) I have a 'table' (i.e a frame) that has n rows (depending on what is in the text file).

As this number could be any number, is it possible to retrieve the number of rows afterwards since I have been given the task where I'm not to use classes but there cannot access the variables etc in the open definition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I used frame_table.grid_size() and have the columns and rows (7, 3).

Sorry for the dull question!